# Manually show Loading/Spinner immediately in onClick of button in React (without waiting for setter)

Tags: reactjs

I have a case where I can't follow the React standard of calling a setter, e.g. `setLoading`, and then checking whether or not to show a component on render, `{loading && <Loading />`.

I have a Submit button which when clicked should immediately show a spinner with no delay, but setters are asynchronous. Therefore I need to do it in `onClick`. When subsequent renders occur, they can read this status and show/hide spinners as usual, with `{loading && <Loading />`.

I was thinking of using `document.getElementById('spinner').style.display = 'block' / 'none'`, but will that work with React renders that show/hide components? Is there a way to force-show a React component right away in JS?

```
<Button type="submit" 
        onClick={() => { 
            // Can't use this setter because it doesn't update right away
            // setIsLoading(true);

            // Is this a good idea? Will subsequent renders read this?
            document.getElementById('spinner').style.display = 'block';
       }}
```

UPDATE: No good solution has been found. To mitigate that small delay before the setter kicks in, we disable the Submit button using Formik's `{isSubmitting}`:

```
<Button type="button" disabled={isSubmitting}> Submit</Button>
```

That at least disables the button so you can't click it again. But immediately showing the spinner is difficult. Even if we force its visibility in `onClick=` that conflicts with React's own variables, so mixing a manual approach with React doesn't work to turn it off. We have to live with that very small delay.

Answer (score 1):

in state add a property for spinner:

```
state = {
  spinnerClass: 'invisible'
}
```

or if you're using a functional component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

// function
let [spinnerClass, updateClass] = useState('invisible');
```

then set some css:

```
.invisible {
  display: none;
/* OR */
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

then add a class to spinner

```
<Spinner className={this.state.spinnerClass} />
/ or
<Spinner className={spinnerClass} />
```

and a function

```
changeClass = () => {
  this.setState({ spinnerClass: '' });
// or
  changeClass('');
}
```

for the button add onclick

```
<button onClick={changeClass} />
```

Comment: But you're still using a setter here, which isn't immediate. Why would this be different? `setSpinnerClass('')`

Comment: if you're going to another page, you could use <Suspense fallback={<Spinner />} >. https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html